# JavaScript: How track() api uses onclick to trigger xss?

Tags: javascript, onclick, xss

Enter the following code to execute alert():

```
 <a id="author" href="http://www.foo.bar?&apos;-alert(1)-&apos;" onclick="var tracker={track(){}};tracker.track('http://www.foo.bar?&apos;-alert(1)-&apos;');">web</a>
```

If I remove the semicolon after the last &apos, alert() will not be executed：

```
 <a id="author" href="http://www.foo.bar?&apos;-alert(1)-&apos" onclick="var tracker={track(){}};tracker.track('http://www.foo.bar?&apos;-alert(1)-&apos');">web</a>
```

Q:

```
1.I don't understand how track() triggers onclick?

2.I'm not sure if the missing semicolon has anything to do with the js syntax?
```

Btw, I'm more interested in knowing how to find answers in similar scenarios.
I will appreciate it if you can help me.

I've tried my best to find the answer：

1.About the first question, I tried to find the answer in MDN ，but found no match。
Then I I google keyword "JS tracker", I'm not sure if this is a help Q&A for track() here https://docs.snowplow.io/docs/collecting-data/collecting-from-own-applications/javascript-trackers/node-js-tracker/node-js-tracker-v3/tracking-events/ ,because I can't understand how it triggers the alert.

2.About the second question, I try the html online editor test, but I think the first question is the key to understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML `&apos;` means "An apostrophe" but `&apos` means "&apos".

An apostrophe is required for this XSS attack to match the previous apostrophe (which is in the code the value from the URL is inserted into) and end that string literal.

Compare:

```
const x = 'some default data'-alert(1)-'';
```

and

```
const x = 'some default data&apos-alert(1)-&apos';
```

Comment: About the first question, I tried to replace other symbols, but they couldn't be executed. Why must a single quotation HTML entity be here to trigger the alert?does the track() function cause it?

Comment: "Why must a single quotation HTML entity be here to trigger the alert?" — See the second paragraph of this answer.

Comment: "does the track() function cause it?" — No. `track` is irrelevant.